# Calculating the electric charge of two spheres knowing their potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, potential

I have a system of two spheres, the first one is at a potential of $ V_1 = 1 V $ and the second one is at a potential of $ V_2 = 0 V $ The distance between them is $d$ and the radius are respectively $r_1$ and $r_2$.

How would i go buy to calculate the charge $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ located on the surface of the spheres ?

I see how to calculate the potential knowing the charge of the spheres (using the image method) but i fail to see how to do it the other way round.

My attempt was to establish the conditions on the limits, for example the potential on the surface of the spheres are known :

$$
\frac{Q_1}{r_1}+\frac{Q2}{d^2+r_1^2+2dr_1*cos(\alpha)^{1/2}}=0
$$

$$
k \times(\frac{Q_2}{r_2}+\frac{Q1}{d^2+r_2^2+2dr_2*cos(\alpha)^{1/2}})=1
$$

with

$$
k = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}
$$

and $\alpha$ the angle between the line linking the centre of the two spheres and the line liking the centre of one sphere to a point on the surface of the other

But i'm not sure how to solve it for $\alpha$ going from 0° to 360°

Is this the right way to proceed ?

Thanks for your help